# Ngx-translate failed to translate all keys

Tags: angular, angular7, ngx-translate

The translations fails on some words (found at least 2 keys that don't work - 'Home' and 'Currency').
The funny thing is that the translation works, but not with all the items...

I've checked the files, no duplicates found for those 2 items that i mentioned above

Home and Currency don't work.
The EN json:
`{
    "Dashboard": "Dashboard",
    "Sellers": "Sellers",
    "Products": "Products",
    "VAT": "VAT",
    "ProductCategory": "Product Categories",
    "ProductDispatch": "Product Dispatch",
    "ProductDispatchSellers": "Product Dispatch Sellers",
    "MeasurementUnits": "Measurement Units",
    "ProductsMasterData": "Products Master Data",
    "ConsignationProducts": "Consignation Products",
    "Documents": "Documents",
    "Orders": "Orders",
    "Invoices": "Invoices",
    "Cashings": "Cashings",
    "Customers": "Customers",
    "CustomerOffices": "Customer Offices",
    "PriceLists": "Price Lists",
    "Currencies": "Currencies",
    "CustomerCategories": "Customer Categories",
    "Routes": "Routes",
    "SalePromotions": "Sale Promotions",
    "Trucks": "Trucks",
    "TruckStocks": "Truck Stocks",
    "Storages": "Storages",
    "Calendar": "Calendar",
    "Consignation": "Consignation",
    "SalesByAgents": "Sales By Agents",
    "SalesByClients": "Sales By Clients",
    "SalesByRegion": "Sales By Region",
    "TransactionSales": "Transaction Sales",
    "Expenses": "Expenses",
    "Surveys": "Surveys",
    "Designer": "Designer",
    "TakeSurvey": "Take Survey",
    "ViewAnswers": "View Answers",
    "Messages": "Messages",
    "SendMessages": "Send Messages",
    "MessageLists": "Message Lists",
    "Activities": "Activities",
    "Target": "Target",
    "ClientActivities": "Client Activities",
    "Admin": "Admin",
    "Users": "Users",
    "Roles": "Roles",
    "XMLLayout": "XML Layout",
    "Reports": "Reports",
    "Settings": "Settings",
    "Add new record": "Add new record",
    "Add user": "Add user",
    "Add role": "Add role",
    "Login": "Login",
    "Password": "Password",
    "Confirm": "Confirm",
    "Person": "Person",
    "Role": "Role",
    "Save": "Save",
    "Close": "Close",
    "Info": "Info",
    "Success": "Success",
    "Warning": "Warning",
    "Error": "Error",
    "msgFillMandatory": "Please fill the mandatory fields",
    "Home": "Home",
    "Currency": "Currency"
}`

The RO json:
`{
    "Dashboard": "Panou de bord",
    "Sellers": "Agenti",
    "Products": "Produse",
    "VAT": "TVA",
    "ProductCategory": "Categorii produse",
    "ProductDispatch": "Livrare produse",
    "ProductDispatchSellers": "Livrare produse vanzatori",
    "MeasurementUnits": "Unitati de masura",
    "ProductsMasterData": "Produse",
    "ConsignationProducts": "Produse de consignatie",
    "Documents": "Documente",
    "Orders": "Comenzi",
    "Invoices": "Facturi",
    "Cashings": "Incasari",
    "Customers": "Clienti",
    "CustomerOffices": "Sedii clienti",
    "PriceLists": "Liste de preturi",
    "Currencies": "Valute",
    "CustomerCategories": "Categorii de clienti",
    "Routes": "Rute",
    "SalePromotions": "Promotii",
    "Trucks": "Vehicule",
    "TruckStocks": "Stoc vehicule",
    "Storages": "Gestiuni",
    "Calendar": "Calendar",
    "Consignation": "Consignatii",
    "SalesByAgents": "Vanzari agenti",
    "SalesByClients": "Vanzari clienti",
    "SalesByRegion": "Vanzari regiuni",
    "TransactionSales": "Tranzactii vanzari",
    "Expenses": "Cheltuieli",
    "Surveys": "Sondaje",
    "Designer": "Designer",
    "TakeSurvey": "Completare sondaj",
    "ViewAnswers": "Vizualizare raspuns",
    "Messages": "Mesaje",
    "SendMessages": "Trimitere mesaj",
    "MessageLists": "Liste mesaje",
    "Activities": "Activitati",
    "Target": "Target",
    "ClientActivities": "Activitati la clienti",
    "Admin": "Admin",
    "Users": "Useri",
    "Roles": "Roluri",
    "XMLLayout": "XML Layout",
    "Reports": "Rapoarte",
    "Settings": "Setari",
    "Add new record": "Adauga inregistrare noua",
    "Add user": "Adaugare utilizator",
    "Add role": "Adaugare rol",
    "Login": "Login",
    "Password": "Parola",
    "Confirm": "Confirmare",
    "Person": "Persoana",
    "Role": "Rol",
    "Save": "Salveaza",
    "Close": "Inchide",
    "Info": "Info",
    "Success": "Succes",
    "Warning": "Avertizare",
    "Error": "Eroare",
    "msgFillMandatory": "Completati campurile obligatorii",
    "Home": "Acasa",
    "Currency": "Valuta"
}`

The html sections are:
`<div class="title-div">
  <label translate>Currency</label>
</div>`

and also:
`<div class="breadcrumb-div">
  <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
  <label>{{'Home' | translate:param }}</label>
</div>`

Comment: why do you do `translate:param`? is `param` a public variable that is defined in your component where use this template?

Comment: @SamVloeberghs Thank you for sharing a thought. I just reused a piece of code that works fine while populating the menu
`<div class="nav-section">
              <div *ngFor="let navPage of navItem.pages" class="nav-item">                  
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="navPage.link" routerLinkActive="selected">
                  <mat-icon>{{navPage.icon}}</mat-icon>
                  {{navPage.heading | translate:param }}</a>
              </div>
            </div>`

Comment: That's why I ask.. Do you have a public variable called `param` in your component class? Do you perhaps get an error in console / developer tools? If so please share it.

Comment: @SamVloeberghs nope. not having a param variable in the .ts file, nor any errors in the console

Comment: than remove the `: param` from `translate: param`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was caused by the fact that an old version of the translation jsons was cached in the dist folder of my Angular project.
Once I deleted it it all went fine.